# Listen to mouse clicks on whole system (not on a JFrame etc.)

Tags: java, event-handling, click, mouse, listener

I want to write a little code which react to a mouse click. But it seems the only way is to listen to clicks on Java components. A direct listener to all clicks would be great.

Is there actually a possibility to implement this in Java?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Found out, that it would need a hook via JNI with some C coding.

More information on
http://www.jotschi.de/?p=90

Best regards,
fnst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don´t think so, because of the sandbox you´re running in.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly possible if you are willing to use a third party library - **[JNativeHook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/)**

It provides these functionality using JNI which is otherwise not possible in pure java apps.

Answer (score 0):

some food for thought: use Point in Java to detect where the click occurs. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html

admittedly, ive only used it once before for detecting rows in a table something like, but it seems the closest to what ive found answering your qn.:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
    //get the coordinates of the mouse click
    Point p = e.getPoint();
    //get the row index that contains that coordinate
    row= target.rowAtPoint(p);
}
```

im sorry if this isn't what you're looking for, but otherwise, clicking on components is the only way to go. whats the alternative- clicking on containers? well that just doesn't make any sense does it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not easy way to accomplish what you want. But what you want could be done.. Well for modern way to accomplish this task, I suggest you examine java.awt.Dialog show method..

```
package mouseclickevent;
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.MenuComponent;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class FrmEvent extends JFrame {
    public FrmEvent(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Test");
        panel.add(btn);
        panel.add(new JTextField("Test"));
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                FrmEvent frm = new FrmEvent();
                frm.setBounds(300,300,  200, 200);
                frm.show();

            }
        });

    }

    private void consumeEvents() {
        try {
            if (Thread.currentThread().getClass().getName().endsWith(
            "EventDispatchThread")) {
                EventQueue eq = null;
                eq = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();

                if (eq == null) {
                    return;
                }
                while (isVisible() || isShowing()) {
                    AWTEvent event = eq.getNextEvent();
                    Object src = event.getSource();
                    Class kActiveEvent= Class.forName("java.awt.ActiveEvent");
                    if (kActiveEvent != null) {
                        if (kActiveEvent.isInstance(event)) {
                            Method m;
                            Class types[] = {};
                            Object args[] = {};
                            m = kActiveEvent.getMethod("dispatch",  types);

                            if (m != null) {
                                m.invoke(event, args);
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    dispatchEvent(src, event);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    private  void dispatchEvent(Object src, AWTEvent event) {
        if (event.getID()== MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED) {
            System.out.println("mouseClicked");
        }
        if (src instanceof Component) {
            ( (Component) src).dispatchEvent(event);
        } else if (src instanceof MenuComponent) {
            ( (MenuComponent) src).dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    }

    public void show(){
        super.show();
        consumeEvents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FrmEvent frm = new FrmEvent();
        frm.setBounds(300,300,  200, 200);
        frm.show();

    }
}
```